# Is it possible to determine whether two lines are intersecting or not, without breaking the joint equation to separate linear equations?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

From the joint equation of a pair of straight lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, is it possible to determine whether the two lines are intersecting or not, without breaking (or factorising) the joint equation to separate linear equations?

I know to find the angle between the lines by the following formula
$$\tan \theta=\left|\frac{2\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{a+b} \right|$$ without finding the individual equations of the lines. Similarly, is there any algorithm to determine whether the lines intersect or not from the joint equation directly?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html

Comment: Well, the lines are either parallel or coincide iff $\tan\theta=0$. Under what conditions does the expression in your question vanish?

Comment: @amd, $h^2=ab$. I have no trouble in understanding that. How to decide whether they are parallel or coincident?

Comment: The table in the link offered by @mathlove provides a complete classification. Another way to distinguish between parallel lines and a double line is to examine the rank of the associated symmetric matrix: a double line has a rank-one matrix. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Discriminant) gives another, equivalent classification method.